# How to handle multiple variables for the same parameter name (for checkbox)?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a code for quiz app, which is having multiple choice for each question.According to my requirement one question may contains multiple correct answer. i'm able to check for single answer if its radio button rather than checkbox. But i need checkbox instead of radio.

So i given checkbox for multiple selection. i used request.POST.getlist('choice') which returns only the order of selection. I can't able to check it with my model whether its correct answer or not.

views.py

```
def checkanswer(request, question_id):
    question = TestQuestion.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    #for single answer checking(if its radio button) i used the following
    #selected_choice = question.testchoice_set.get(pk=request.POST.get('choice'))
    a = request.POST.getlist('choice')
    #print(selected_choice.is_answer)
    #if selected_choice.is_answer == 'Yes':
        #return HttpResponse('Right')
    return HttpResponse('Wrong')
```

test.html

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:checkanswer' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.testchoice_set.all %}
      <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
      <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_opt }}</label><br />
 {% endfor %}
 <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
 </form>
```

I expect, each option chooses by the user need to be checked with data base whether its right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your Question Model has four options op1 to op4. Then you can store four different values (each set to T/F)  and can check these like this.

Note that option1 to option4 stores the text only and op1 to op4 are boolean to show whether that option is true or not. 
For example if your answer is ABD set op3 to false and others to true. 
class AssessmentQuestion(models.Model):

```
text             =   models.TextField()
question_image   =   models.FileField(upload_to = upload_image_path_questions, null = True, blank = True)

option1          =   models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2200)
option2          =   models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2200)
option3          =   models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2200)
option4          =   models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2200)

op1              =   models.BooleanField(default=False)
op2              =   models.BooleanField(default=False)
op3              =   models.BooleanField(default=False)
op4              =   models.BooleanField(default=False)

integer_type     =   models.BooleanField(default=False)
single_option    =   models.BooleanField(default=False)
integeral_answer = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
```

And in views.py access the response from the template in integer and match with op1. This will work for single correct as well as for multiple correct. If you want an integral answer also then you can use that too.

```
                    p = int(current_question.op1) == int(request.data.get('op1'))
                    q =   int(current_question.op2) == int(request.data.get('op2')) 
                    r = int(current_question.op3) == int(request.data.get('op3')) 
                    s =  int(current_question.op4) == int(request.data.get('op4'))

                     if(p & q& r& s):
                         print('answer correct')
                         correct = True



                     else:
                         print('Incorrect multiple answer')
                         correct = False
```

Comment: In my quiz app, i used form set for choice so its dynamic field, multiple choice means we cannot fix the no of choice. May a question can have 5 choice. In that case what will be the option?

Comment: Saran, Use a ForeignKey to Question in your choices Model and in views.py loop over every choice to match the condition. That will be much easier to implement. Just follow the very same way and iterate over all present choices for a question.

Comment: Ishwar, We cannot fix the choice.May be one question have 3 choice, what if a i want 5 choice for another question.

Comment: I'm not saying to fix that. I am saying to add a foreign key and add as many numbers of choices you need. ONE TO MANY RELATION

Comment: okay Ishwar, i have one doubt, why did you use request.data.get() instead of request.POST.get()?

Comment: Actually, I created it in mind of making an API call. You can use request.POST.get() for simple views as you are doing with HTML file.